# Easiest way to embed flash in a page?

Tags: nodes

I am looking to embed flash in D7 on a simple page. How would I do this?

Comment: If it is really a simple page, then you can create a basic page and enter embed code in body field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create a new text field for embed flash. Be sure that your WYSIWYG filter will allow the embed and object tags.